# Blackberry Custom Background of VFM scrolls with listfield?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I want to "fix" the Background while only the ListFields scrolls.

Current Problem:

[image]

Scrolling Down (the surounding box should move with the List)

[image]

Corresponding code for the VerticalFieldManager

```
VerticalFieldManager _bottom_box = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
        {
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
            {
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setExtent(maxWidth - 6, maxHeight - 3);
            }
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.clear();
                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                graphics.fillRect(0, 0, (this.getWidth()), (this.getHeight()));
                graphics.setColor(color_computacenter_light_blue);
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, (this.getWidth()), (this.getHeight()));
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };
```

Any Ideas, how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to know without more info about the structure of that screen, but the root cause is something to do with the difference between the visible height on screen (given by getHeight()) and the virtual height.  You're drawing to the virtual viewport with that paint method, so I think this tweak should fix things:

```
                    protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
                    {
                            graphics.clear();
                            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            graphics.fillRect(0, graphics.getClippingRect().y, (this.getWidth()), (this.getHeight()));
                            graphics.setColor(color_computacenter_light_blue);
                            graphics.drawRect(0, graphics.getClippingRect().y, (this.getWidth()), (this.getHeight()));
                            super.paint(graphics);
                    }
```

Comment: Hi, Anthony *g. You seem to be the only blackberry specialist on stackoverflow.com. As you can see, my project is evoling.

Comment: Fixed it: Simple, just put another VFM around the ListField :)

Comment: coldice seems to be a BB regular here as well  :)

Comment: hey u can set the height of the vertical field manager which holds ur list field and it will scroll in that particular space